# Arzela-Ascoli Anthony Knapp Proof

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

**STATEMENT:** (Arzela Ascoli Theorem) If $\left\{f_n\right\}$ is an equicontinuous family of scalar-valued functions defined on a compact Hausdorff space $X$ and if $\left\{f_n\right\}$ has the property that $\left\{f_n(x)\right\}$ is bounded for each $x$, then $\left\{f_n\right\}$ has a uniformly convergent subsequence.

Proof: We may assume that there are infinitely many distinct functions $f_n$, since otherwise the assertion is trivial. Let $|f_n(x)|\leq c_x$ for all $n$, and form the product space $C=\prod_{x\in X}\left\{z\in \mathbb{C}\mid |z|\leq c_x\right\} $. The space $C$ is compact by Tychonoff theorem, and we are now assuming that there are infinitely many members of the sequence $\left\{f_n\right\}$ in the space. Let $S$ be the image of the sequences as a subset of $C$. If $S$ were to contain all its limit points, then each $f_n$ would have an open neighborhood in $C$ disjoint from the rest of $S$; these open sets and $S^c$ would form an open cover of $C$ with no finite sub cover, in contradiction to compactness of $C$. Thus $S$ has a limit point $f$ not in $S$. By Lemma 10.47 and the remarks before it, the family $S\cup \left\{f\right\}$ is equicontinuous.

Lemma 10.47: Let $\mathcal{F}=\left\{f_\alpha\right\}$ is equicontinuous at $x$ in $X$, then the closure $\mathcal{F}^{cl}$ of $\mathcal{F}$ in the product topology on $\mathbb{C}^X$ is equicontinuous at $x$.

**QUESTION:** How does Knapp conclude that each $f_n$ would have an open neighborhood in $C$ disjoint from $S$.

Comment: Not disjoint from $S$, disjoint _from the rest of_ $S$. It's however not true. If for example $f_n \to f_0$ uniformly and all $f_n$ are distinct, then every neighbourhood of $f_0$ intersects $S\setminus \{f_0\}$ and $S$ contains all its limit points.

Comment: What if we consider $X$ as a singleton set, with the discrete topology. And we let $f_n(x)=1/n$ union with the zero function, then wouldn't this be contradictory to Knapp's claim since its images points form a closed set, but $0$ doesn't have a disjoint open neighborhood.

Comment: Yes. That's a specific example of the situation I described. (Note: on a singleton set, there is only one topology, the discrete topology and the indiscrete topology coincide on singletons.)

Comment: Then is there a flaw with Knapp's proof or do we just simply ignore the problematic points?

Comment: There certainly is a flaw in Knapp's proof. I don't know how the proof goes on, so no idea whether it's a minor thing or something harder to fix.

Comment: I will add on the rest of the proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The assertion

> If $S$ were to contain all its limit points, then each $f_n$ would have an open neighborhood in $C$ disjoint from the rest of $S$

is incorrect. If for example $(f_n)$ is a sequence of distinct functions uniformly converging to $f_0$ (or $f_1$ if for you $0\notin \mathbb{N}$), then $S$ is a closed subset of $C$, hence contains all its limit points, and every neighbourhood of $f_0$ intersects $S\setminus \{f_0\}$.

The mistake is easily fixable, however. The goal here is to show the existence of a limit point of $S$. So if $S$ contains a limit point of $S$, we are done. And if $S$ had no limit points - that is, $S$ contains all its limit points and no $f_n$ is a limit point of $S$ - **then** the assertion that each $f_n$ has an open neighbourhood disjoint from $S\setminus \{f_n\}$ holds. And in that case, the part of the proof shows by contradiction that $S$ must have a limit point contra the assumption.

However, it is a fundamental property of compact spaces that every infinite subset of a compact space has a limit point, so I don't see the point of that particular argument.

Answer (score 3):

This error is corrected in Knapp’s errata, which can be found [here](https://www.math.sunysb.edu/~aknapp/books/basic/b-real-corrections18.pdf). (The uncorrected proof can be seen [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=4ZZCAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA478&ots=f6ikA2mQbZ&dq=If%20S%20were%20to%20contain%20all%20its%20limit%20points%2C%20then%20each%20fn%20would%20have%20an%20open%20neighborhood&pg=PA478#v=onepage&q&f=false).)

The phrase “contain all its limit points” should read “have no limit point in $C$.”